# HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid using SharePoint Application Proxy

Tags: sharepoint-server, hybrid-solution, proxy

Has anyone else experienced this error after completing the SharePoint Application Proxy deployment?

I have the Proxy connector set up and I have added all the required information in my Azure Active Directory(Internal URL and SPN for SSO).  When I run the Test Application Proxy Configuration report, I have all green checkmarks(picture below).  So I am confused as to why I am getting this error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Please following steps:**

1. Go to SharePoint Central Administration >> System Settings >> Manage services on server >> Request Management
2. Stop service and it will work fine.

[image]

There is a similar case in the Q&A forum for your reference：

- [HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid using SharePoint Application Proxy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/481715/http-error-400-the-request-hostname-is-invalid-usi.html)

Comment: That similar case is mine as well, actually.  Unfortunately, the service was already stopped and so the problem still persists.  Any other tips?